# X11 and pygame in Crontab

Tags: x11, cron, python

I have a script very similar to the one at the end of the pygame example [page](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html), and I want to run it on startup to make the whole thing listen for commands on startup. I ran "crontab -e" and as a first line I put "@reboot python3 myscript.py". Upon rebooting, the script doesn't work, and returns pygame.error: video system not initialized. On the other hand, if I execute "python3 myscript.py" from the terminal, the script works.

The vast majority of answers simply notes that pygame.init() is not called, which is not the case here. According to a [post](https://forum-raspberrypi.de/forum/thread/19897-pygame-error-video-system-not-initialized/) translated from German, this can be solved by exporting a variable somewhere, but I am not sure where or how to do that.

Is there a way to give X11 privileges to the script ran on reboot by Crontab?

UPDATE:
Upon chaining commands like Seamus suggested, setting DISPLAY=:0 doesn't work at all. From terminal after login, I did echo $DISPLAY and got :1. When setting:

```
@reboot (sleep 30; export DISPLAY=:1; python3 /full/path/to/myscript.py)
```

it starts working after login, but not before (which is my main requirement, as the device should be autonomous). I am not sure if this :1 is relevant and what is :0.

Comment: I'm confused... you've said `The script doesn't work...`, but in the next sentence you've said, `The script works fine when ran from terminal normally.` Could you clear this up, please?

Comment: It doesn't work when ran on startup by crontab, it works fine when I run it from CLI. I will try to edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: OK - that will help, but knowing that's the case I have an idea where the problem is. I'll post my answer momentarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script runs from the command line, but not from `cron`, there are two usual suspects:

1. The PATH for `cron` is different than your path as a "regular" user. You can address that issue by using a full path spec for your script:

```
@reboot python3 /full/path/to/myscript.py
```

2. `cron` is unaware of the status of any services when it starts. For `cron`, `@reboot` means when `cron` starts, not when the network is up, or any other services your `cron` job may require. One way to take care of this is to `sleep` for a bit before running your script:

```
@reboot (sleep 30; python3 /full/path/to/myscript.py)
```

This will delay execution of your script by 30 seconds. Nothing magic about 30 seconds... it will depend upon your system. You may wish to do some trial and error testing to find a reliable sleep time.

Note that another approach that avoids `cron`'s shortcomings wrt status of system services is to use `systemd`. Some (myself included) find `cron` easier to use, but certainly `systemd` has some advantages.

Finally, it's usually a good idea to collect any error messages generated when starting your script. Another addition to the single line in your `crontab` will accomplish that:

```
@reboot (sleep 30; python3 /full/path/to/myscript.py >> /home/yours/cronjoblog) 2>&1
```

Any error messages from `stderr`  will be appended to the file you designate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Uknowningly, I avoided both problems you are mentioning - I did use the full path and made an infinite loop of trying and logging - it reports the same error long after the system has started up.
I also try the initialisation step over and over, so I feel like the right solution is passing the display variable. The only problem is I am not sure how.

Comment: @CindyAlmighty: Sorry that didn't help. You might look into the ~/.Xauthority file for a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find the ~/.Xauthority file, or the environment variable. I looked at this post and I don't have the equivalent either - the path doesn't exist (I have /var/run/gdm3/greeter/...).

Comment: Wish I could help more... I'm not a frequent user of X, but was under the impression that `~/.Xauthority` was required. But it seems you've narrowed the problem down a bit. Maybe post another question focused on your edited question?

Comment: True. This is solid advice for running Crontab. Cheers!